# Storing Password Reset Questions in LDAP

Tags: security, encryption, active-directory, ldap, passwords

I want to store answers to password reset questions in LDAP. I know that the answers should be hashed with a salt. I would like insight into the following:

- What attributeClass should we use?
- Is it possible to get the LDAP server to perform the hashing operations?
- Is there a way to use the LDAP compare operation if the container doesn't expose how it performs hashing?
- Does the answer vary depending on which directory service vendor you go with?
- Is it possible to extend the password attributeClass for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

I have looked for such functionality in Sun Directory Server but was not able to find it. I ended up implementing it in my client code (by using java.security.MessageDigest if I remember correctly). It wasn't much work, but I would have prefered it to be handled by the server.

UPDATE

Oracle Internet Directory 11g supports hashing attributes:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17904_01/oid.1111/e10029/data_privacy.htm#BABFFHIH

Answer (score 0):

Just an Idea that might be totally off, why not have a duplicate account of each user where the password is the answer to the secret question?
This way you won't have to think about hashing/salt/encryption and to validate the answer you will call the logon user API.
Those duplicate users of course will belong to a very limited security groups.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to define an attribute for the security question/answer using the syntax of an attribute that is subject to hashing/encryption, such as userPassword. This depends on the directory server product you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Any directory-string attribute type (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4517#page-8) can be used if you want to store the hashed/encrypted value as readable string, say, Base64-encoded. You could also store it in any octet string attribute type (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4517#page-19).

If the answers to the security questions need to be recovered or some leniency during verification (e.g., mixed/lower/upper case indifference) is needed, encryption may be a better option. It'd be preferable to have the middleware to do this too. Like Terry Gardner said, it depends on the directory server software you're using. For example, IBM Security Directory Server can be configured to encrypt the values of attributes. The encryption is done using the security elements specified during the installation of the software. The application doesn't have to do anything special. Novell, Red Hat, and Oracle/Sun Directory Server software also support encrypted attributes. I'm not an AD expert, but I think it doesn't support encrypted attributes. I think it's the same for OpenLDAP.